# Can I develop in orbeon but save to a mysql db?

Tags: xhtml, xforms, orbeon

Am developing an application using xforms and its the first web based application am working on, so completely new to all this but we all start from somewhere right? I have been coding from IBM's visual form designer but since its not at all user friendly I have been writting the codes myself as I learn. Now my deadline is catching up and am still behind. Being tempted to use Orbeon forms but I know nothing about it. What are the conns and pros of Orbeon forms? Can i use it to design my interface but then interact with a mysql database? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Orbeon Forms to [store data in MySQL](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers) for forms you create in Form Builder. The data will be stored in [Orbeon-specific tables](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers#TOC-MySQL). If you need the data to end up in some custom tables that you already have, you can setup [triggers in MySQL](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers#TOC-MySQL2) to insert the data in your own table when Orbeon Forms adds the data to its own tables.

Comment: Thanks avernet, will check it out.